# Simple C# WMI Get & Put

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to Read  & Put values from and to WMI using C#.

The current example uses ccm namespace, for configmgr client.

The read functions works correctly, able to read ADV_RepeatRunBehavior value.
Though the Put(); doesn't work as expected, the values are not stored back and Invalid Class exception is thrown.

Some advice would be nice as I am new to this, many thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "root\\ccm\\Policy\\Machine", 
            "SELECT * FROM CCM_SoftwareDistribution WHERE PKG_PackageID='XXXXXXXX'");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            //Read works
            //Console.WriteLine(queryObj["ADV_RepeatRunBehavior"].ToString());
            //Console.ReadLine();

            //Put doesn't
            queryObj["ADV_RepeatRunBehavior"] = "RerunNever";
            queryObj.Put();
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException z)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + z.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the docs, "test" doesn't look like a valid value for that property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc145304.aspx

Comment: @IanGilroy Thanks, unfortuantely still doesn't work with original properties provided by msdn lib. 
It definitely isn't valid property, but it should be possible to change the value to whatever. F.e. I can change it to anything via wbemtest. Of course at the result/testing phase I will ensure valid properties inserted only, as well edited the posted script.

Answer (score 1):

Found the resolution for this.

1. You have to run Visual Studio as Administrator if testing on localhost
2. The connection to WMI has to be `\\root\\ccm\\Policy\\Machine\\ActualConfig` then its possible to Put() values.